# Wrong Express API resource call by order

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

I ran into an interesting problem. I have four different get endpoints, all of them contain query parameters.

```
router.get('/',getProducts)
router.get('/keyfilter',getFilterByKey)
router.get('/advancedfilters',getFilterProducts)
router.get('/:productId',getProductById)
```

In this case works fine. When I move my fourth endpoint above the keyfilter and advancefilter I can't access them even if I called the right one. If I move the fourth endpoint at the top of all endpoints the basic `getProducts` endpoint can be called, but the others not. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because Express cannot know that there is no product with productId = "advancedfilters". It assumes "advancedfilters" is a product id

Answer (score 1):

> If I move the fourth endpoint at the top of all endpoints the basic getProducts endpoint can be called, but the others not. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

That's because this one:

```
router.get('/:productId',getProductById)
```

Matches every single top level GET route.  The route specifier `'/:productId'` is essentially a wildcard.  Any top level path will match it.  So, if you put it first, then it steals every single top level GET request and takes it.

I do not make top level wildcard routes in my servers because of this issue.  I would suggest that you either put it under a prefix such as:

```
router.get('/id/:productId',getProductById)
```

Or, you use a regex and filter out the matches to only something that meets a fairly strict criteria that matches an actual productId, letting everything else fall through to the other route handlers.  The regex would only work if your productIds are uniquely identifiable in a regex and will never be confused with other top level routes.

The problem with a top level wildcard route, even if you put it last is that it creates many possible conflicts for future API growth in your server and ANY new top level route you create might conflict with an existing productId route.  You don't want that.  I personally think it would be better to just never have a top level wildcard route and use the prefix mechanism illustrated above.